# Need help getting FadeTo method to work with window scroll event

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scroll, fadeto

I am trying to get each '**section**' of my one page website Fade in and out based on the scroll position. I want the section's to remain as display:block so I am using the **FadeTo** method rather than FadeIn/FadeOut.

The idea is to have each section fadein when it reaches a certain distance from the top and fadeout when it doesn't meet certain requirements. My current markup attempt is as follows but struggling on figuring out where I am making the mistake

**Function:**

```
function scrollFadeDiv(element, navheight) {
    var offset = element.offset();
    var offsetTop = offset.top;
    var totalScroll = offsetTop - navheight;


    if (totalScroll > 0 ){
        $(element).fadeTo('slow', 0.0); 
    } else {
        $(element).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    }


}
```

**and my window scroll event:**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var elWrapped = $('section');
    scrollFadeDiv(elWrapped, 75);
});
```

My concern is that since **live()** has been deprecated and **delegate()** doesn't work with the scroll event than, the totalScroll variable won't continually be updated/re-calculated after the DOM has been loaded.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the waypoints plugin:

https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints

Comment: Thanks Lucuma, this solution worked just fine. I am still looking to find out where I went wrong just for the sake of having a better understanding and improve my craft. Thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: Build a jsfiddle to demonstrate a specific problem and post that to your question.  I'm not sure the issue has anything to do with live and delegate which have analogs in the newer jquery versions.